# Execution time of a query - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections: coach and team. 
Coach collection contains information about coaches like name, surname, age and an array coached_Team that contains the ***_id*** of the team that a coach coached.
The team collection contains data about teams like ***_id***, common name, official name, country, championship....
If I want to find, for example, the official name of all teams coached by Allegri, I have to do two queries, the first on coach collection:

```
>var x = db.coach.find({surname:"Allegri"},{_id:0, "coached_Team.team_id":1})
>var AllegriTeams
>while(x.hasNext()) AllegriTeams=x.next()
{
    "coached_Team" : [
            {
                    "team_id" : "Juv.26
            },
            {
                    "team_id" : "Mil.74
            },
            {
                    "team_id" : "Cag.00
            }
    ]
}
>AllegriTeams=AllegriTeams.coached_Team
[
    {
            "team_id" : "Juv.26"
    },
    {
            "team_id" : "Mil.74"
    },
    {
            "team_id" : "Cag.00"
    }
]
```

And then I have to execute three queries on team collection:

```
> db.team.find({ _id:AllegriTeams[0].team_id}, {official_name:1,_id:0})
{official_name : "Juventus Football Club S.p.A."}
> db.team.find({ _id:AllegriTeams[1].team_id}, {official_name:1,_id:0})
{official_name : "Associazione Calcio Milan S.p.A"}
> db.team.find({ _id:AllegriTeams[2].team_id}, {official_name:1,_id:0})
{official_name:"Cagliari Calcio S.p.A"}
```

Now consider I have about 100k documents on collection team and collection coach. The first query, on coach collection, needs about 71 ms plus the time of while cycle. The three queries on team collection, using cursor.explain("executionStats") needs 0 ms. I don't understand why this query takes 0. 
I need executionTimeMillis of these three queries to have the execution time of the query *"find official names of all teams coached by Allegri"*. I want to add the execution time of the query on coach collection(71ms) with the execution time of these three. If the time of these three queries is 0 what can I say about the execution time of the query mainly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the more important observation here is that 71ms is a long time for a simple fetch of one item. Looks like your "surname" field needs an index. The other "three" queries are simple lookups of a primary key, which is why they are relatively fast.

```js
db.coach.createIndex({ "surname": 1 })
```

If that surname is actually "unique" then add that too:

```js
db.coach.createIndex({ "surname": 1 },{ "unique": true })
```

You can also simplify your "three" queries as as one by simply mapping the array, and applying the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```js
var teamIds = [];

db.coach.find(
    { "surname": "Allegri" },
    { "_id":0, "coached_Team.team_id":1 }
).forEach(function(coach) {
    teamIds = coach.coached_Team.map(function(team) {
        return team.team_id }).concat(teamIds);
    });
});

db.team.find(
    { "_id": { "$in": teamIds"  }},
    { "official_name": 1, "_id": 0 }
).forEach(function(team) {
    printjson(team);
});
```

And then certainly the overall execution time is way down, as well as removing the overhead of multiple operations down to just the two queries requried.

Also remembering here that despite what is in the execution plan stats, the more queries to make to and from the server then the longer the overal real time execution will be for making each request and retriving the data. So it is best to keep things as minimal as possible.

Therefore even more logical would be that where to "need" this information regularly, storing the "coach name" on the "team itself" ( and indexing that data ) leads to the fastest possible response and only a single query operation.

It's easy to get caught up in observing execution stats. But really, think of what is "best" and "fastest" as a pattern for the sort of queries you want to do.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you. Just another thing.
When I create an index on a field, is it normal that the `executionTimeMillis` of a query on that field is 0? Maybe it depends on the low number of documents(100k) in the collection team. If I added 1 million instead of 100k documents, the executionTimeMillis would be different after index creation?

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana It "depends" on quite a lot of things. In general an "index" should be much smaller than your overall data. As such, any database "strives" to keep that index data in memory "first" and then later the other working data of the actual collection. So the seek times should then at least be optimal, with the other "paged" information that is generally being used. Is it "normal"? It depends, but is it "desirable"? Then absolutely.